# Recibir POST en llamada FETCH en VUE

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Siguiendo el API de fetch en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch escribo el siguiente método en VUE, estoy trabajando en local, y con VUE y VUETIFY llamándolos por CDN, sin instalación npm.

```html
<body>
....
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="./productes.js"></script>
</body>
```

```html
imprimir()
{
    var fetchData = 
    {   
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'comanda': this.comanda})
    }
    fetch('./imprimir.php', fetchData)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log("print pdf -> ", data);

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
},
```

La respuesta en imprimir.php, que ahora en estos momentos tengo solo para imprimir el $_POST por pantalla.

```html
$posted_data = $_POST['comanda'];
$data = json_decode($posted_data);
    
echo $data;
print_r($data);
```

La llamada parece correcta, pero el $_POST está vacío. El parámetro pasado por POST es de la forma:

```html
0: {referencia: "p_0001", producte: "Producte 1", quantitat: 1, preu: "2.00", iva: "4.00", base: 2,…}
base: 2
iva: "4.00"
preu: "2.00"
producte: "Producte 1"
quantitat: 1
referencia: "p_0001"
total: "2.08"
totaliva: "0.08"
```

¿A qué se debe que el $_POST esté vacío?

En el Request Payload me muestra:

```html
{"comanda":[{"referencia":"p_0001","producte":"Producte 1","quantitat":1,"preu":"2.00","iva":"4.00","base":2,"totaliva":"0.08","total":"2.08"},{"referencia":"p_0002","producte":"Producte 2","quantitat":1,"preu":"4.00","iva":"4.00","base":4,"totaliva":"0.16","total":"4.16"},{"referencia":"p_0003","producte":"Producte 3","quantitat":1,"preu":"6.00","iva":"10.00","base":6,"totaliva":"0.60","total":"6.60"}]}
```

Y haciendo console.log(this.comanda) como primera instrucción dentro de imprimir me muestra en consola esto:

```html
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: base: 2iva: "4.00"preu: "2.00"producte: "Producte 1"quantitat: 1referencia: "p_0001"total: "2.08"totaliva: "0.08"__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}get base: ƒ reactiveGetter()set base: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get iva: ƒ reactiveGetter()set iva: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get preu: ƒ reactiveGetter()set preu: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get producte: ƒ reactiveGetter()set producte: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get quantitat: ƒ reactiveGetter()set quantitat: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get referencia: ƒ reactiveGetter()set referencia: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get total: ƒ reactiveGetter()set total: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get totaliva: ƒ reactiveGetter()set totaliva: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)__proto__: Object1: {…}
2: base: (...)iva: (...)preu: (...)producte: (...)quantitat: (...)referencia: (...)total: (...)totaliva: (...)__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}get base: ƒ reactiveGetter()set base: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get iva: ƒ reactiveGetter()set iva: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get preu: ƒ reactiveGetter()set preu: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get producte: ƒ reactiveGetter()set producte: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get quantitat: ƒ reactiveGetter()set quantitat: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get referencia: ƒ reactiveGetter()set referencia: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get total: ƒ reactiveGetter()set total: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get totaliva: ƒ reactiveGetter()set totaliva: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)__proto__: Objectlength: 3__ob__: Observer {value: Array(3), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}__proto__: Array
```

Una de las cosas que he probado, es a realizar un post con Python de la siguiente forma:

```html
import requests
url = 'http://localhost/php_py/imprimir.php'
datos = {'num': 1}
x = requests.post(url,data=datos)
print(x.text)
```

Con esto, el Php si que imprime el post recibido:

```html
Array
(
    [num] => 1
)
```

Añado también que si hago en el fetch, un GET, de esta forma:

```html
fetch('http://localhost/php_py/imprimir.php?comanda='+JSON.stringify(this.comanda))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Si que recibo los datos en el Php, y puedo verlos al hacer el print_r($_GET)

Comment: que vale `this.comanda` ? aparentemente en tu codigo javascript no se ve definida dicha variable, tiene pinta de que estas enviando una cadena vacia. Yo probaria primero el php con postman o curl, enviando el body correspondiente y viendo si responde adecuadamente. Si no sale lo esperado, el php esta mal, si sale lo que esperas es que no estas enviando correctamente el payload.

Comment: this.comanda la he definido en la sección data, y le voy añadiendo información, tiene el valor que indico en la última parte del post, 0: {referencia: "p_0001", producte: "Producte 1", ...}, a parte puedo ver this.comanda en el payload.

Comment: confirmame esto: pon en el metodo imprimir() al principio del todo un console.log(this.comanda) (antes de la asignacion de fetchData y dinos que te muestra. Despues confirma con postman que enviando un post de tipo json te devuelve lo  mismo que envias.

Comment: Te faltan las cabeceras para que se maneje como un objeto nativo desde php a vuejs, agrega en tu archivo PHP antes de hacer el "echo" esto: header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

Comment: Añado el header, e imprimo el $_POST con print_r($_POST) pero sigue estando vacío, no he utilizado nunca postman. Estroy trabajando en local.

Comment: Tiene que ver este problema, estar utilizando Vue i Vuetify con CDN, sin instalación npm??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto la cuestión capturando el POST de la siguiente forma:

```html
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Consultado en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250688/fetch-doesnt-send-post-data

Pero no acabo de entender porque es necesario el file_get_contents..